# Are different telnet connections with the same endpoints valid in different threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, ssh, telnet, tcpclient

I'd like to connect to a telnet server multiple times and use each connection in its own thread. So, I'd be using multiple sessions that have the same endpoints concurrently.

I'm using `TcpClient` and a very simple, home-made telnet library. In my tests, single connections work fine, and multiple connections in different threads work fine when I use a static lock object. When I remove the lock, I get unexpected responses from the server (it looks like the server is responding to a request made on a different thread).

The thing that confuses me is that, when I run a single connection per application but multiple *applications* (which are running concurrently), everything works fine.

Is what I am trying to do valid with telnet? Would there be a difference when using SSH?

**This does not seem to work**:

```
Application
    Client-
           \
            <-> Server
           /
    Client-
```

**This seems to work**:

```
Application
    Client <-> Server
Application
    Client <-> Server
```

I have verified that I am indeed creating different TCP connections (different instances of `TcpClient`) per session in the multi-threaded application.

Comment: How are you using TcpClient (show a bit of code)? What telnet server are you connecting to?

Comment: `Is what I am trying to do valid with telnet?` Yes.  `Would there be a difference when using SSH?` No. For more detailed answer post the details of your code.

Comment: Thanks @L.B - I think I was mostly trying to make sure I wasn't expecting something to work that couldn't possibly work. I think I've narrowed it down to an issue with the program I'm running in the telnet session (it's a program that keeps the std in/out open and I write/read directly to it). If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it. (Though, I've read that a telnet server identifies its clients by their IP and port, so if you can explain how that works with multiple connections from the same client, I'd be interested in hearing it.)

Comment: When you open multiple connections from a client, all connections will have different port. Sorry that there is no magic.